# red normals produce correct shading while blue normals produce bad shading

Tags: shaders, normals, artifacts

Isnt it supposed to be like the visible part of the object from the camera should be blue?

Also i have this large object with many details, some of the parts look correct with blue normals and some with red normals, i am probably doing something wrong but cant figure out what

[image]

example with blue normal:[image]
[image]

example with red normal:[image]
[image]

Comment: You are doing some really weird stuff to the normal map in the shader. It's possible to invert normals in the shader. Unfortunately you have not packed the images to your file, so there is no way to tell if any of that makes sense. There is an Invert node in the group for one channel though and another is subtracted from 1 at some point... so... It seems likely you simply invert normals in the shader. Why is the shader so complicated?

Comment: The normal map used is a compressed unity normal map, i saw some tutorials on how to  extract the usable normal map from this compressed one. So i am guessing my unpack node doesn't work properly, because i tried it with other materials and they work fine. Thank you for helping me find the problem.